# Pass comma separated Key Value Dict elements and form an array in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary

Pass comma separated Key Value Dict elements and form an array in python

I have provided a sample code for dict_to_array.py below.
I would like to run this dict_to_array.py with the command line input and receive the expected output.

What should be the code changes to get the expected output. Should I also change the input pattern?

> Command Line Input: {"name":"JK","value":"37"},{"name":"MK","value":"25"}"

> Expected Output: "input_variables": [{"name":"JK","value":"37"},{"name":"MK","value":"25"}]

```
import json

import sys

data = { 'input_variables': sys.argv[1] }

job_data = json.dumps(data)

print(job_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse them as json array. This should work

`python3 file.py '{"name":"JK","value":"37"},{"name":"MK","value":"25"}'`

```
import json

import sys

data = { 'input_variables': json.loads('[{}]'.format(sys.argv[1])) }

job_data = json.dumps(data)

print(job_data)
```